# JAVA фиксированное количество запусков функции

Tags: java

Есть второй поток, в нём функция в бесконечном цикле. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы эта функция срабатывала фиксированное кол-во раз в единицу времени? (например 10 раз в секунду)

Comment: Можно. Такого ответа достаточно? ;-)

Comment: Да, задал вопрос не правильно)
Как это сделать?)

Comment: используй `static` переменные

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, уточните что именно вызывает сложности (например что мешает добавить счетчик и сверяться с текущим временем)

Comment: если добавить проверку со временем, то не будет ли такого, что при большой загрузке процессора, ф-я в кокой-то момент не выполнится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // здесь функция, которая вызывается каждые 100 миллисекунд = 10 раз в секунду
    // она изначальна вызывается в другом потоке
}, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```